# Reducing TreeViewItem heights

Tags: wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

Ive got a TreeView with a HierarchicalDataTemplate.  But the spacing between the final nodes is to big (see image below).
I tried adding a ItemContainStyle like:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="15" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But this resticts the hight of expanded parent nodes - and hence chops off all the nodes children.  If I use above to set MinHeight to say 30 I can increase the node spacing but I want to do the opposite - any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should change treeviewitemtemplate.